# Postgresql on ubuntu localhost connection where address?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I installed a fresh copy of postgresql on Ubuntu 14.04. As

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

I can easily use psql make db, table, etc fine. But I'm interested use java to connect and insert some data. But I don't know what is address. I assume something like:-

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:8080/database name", "username",         "password");

But I could not connect. So the question is that what is the address for a freshly installed copy of psql on ubuntu?

Comment: postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL listens on TCP/IP port 5432 on the loopback address 127.0.0.1 (IPv4) and ::1 IPv6) by default. These are generally bound to the hostname 'localhost'.

So the JDBC URL is:

```
jdbc:postgressql://localhost:5432/dbname
```

However, the port is assumed to be 5432 if you don't supply it; all you need is

```
jdbc:postgressql://localhost/dbname
```

For more information [see the manual](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/connect.html).

---

BTW, "psql" is the client program. PostgreSQL or "postgres" is the server.